# What is the general formula (parametric expression) for a surface generated by rotating y=f(x) around y-axis?

Tags: calculus, rotations, surfaces, parametric, parametrization

Here is a simpler version of my question.
Given curve $\displaystyle y=f(x)$ rotated around the y-axis. The generated surface can be described with parameters $\displaystyle x$ and $\displaystyle \theta$. Which parametrization below is correct for that surface?

> A) $\displaystyle (f(x)\cos(\theta ),f(x),f(x)\sin(\theta ))$

or

> B) $\displaystyle (x\cos(\theta ),f(x),x\sin(\theta ))$

I think B is correct, and I think A is incorrect.  But, I usually trust Wikipedia and it essentially states that A is the correct answer.
[See section Coordinate expressions on Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution)

Comment: I agree with you that answer B is correct. The surface being the curve $y = f(x)$ rotated around the $y$-axis, it must at least include each point of the curve with no rotation, i.e. for $\theta = 0$ we must have $(x, f(x), 0)$.

Comment: Thank you Jean-Armand... At least 1 person agrees with me.  I would like to give you credit for answering, but I will self-answer with the confidence that someone agrees with me.

Comment: B is the correct answer.
The parametrization of the surface generated by rotating y=f(x) aound the y-axis is:
$\displaystyle (x\cos(\theta ),f(x),x\sin(\theta ))$

Comment: That's perfect. I'll try to correct Wikipedia.

Comment: While correcting Wikipedia, I just realized that the correct formula was already present on Wikipedia a few lines after the incorrect one, with the parameterization on $t$.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Armand.  Wikipedia now seems to show correct parametrizations for both (one based on x and $\displaystyle \theta$ and the other based on t and $\displaystyle \theta$).